# Can we resize the EBS volume when snapshot is in progress?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-ebs, snapshot

I've an ec2 instance with root volume and additional volume attached, additional volume is 92% used.

I took a ebs snapshot , but looks like its very slow.

Can I go ahead and increase the volume size and expand the volume while snapshot is in progress ? or should I wait until the snapshot is finished ? Is it safe?

Comment: Your snapshot is safe once your started taking it. However, I am not sure if AWS will allow you to expand the volume while the snapshot operation is going on. If it allows you to do it, then you are safe.

Comment: so we can also extend while its optimizing?

Answer (score 2):

Just if in case anyone has the same question, I was able to expand my volume while the volume was optimizing and when snapshot was in progress.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/WindowsGuide/recognize-expanded-volume-windows.html

Comment: What is "optimizing" in the context of EBS? Snapshot and resize are operations I've heard of, but not Optimizing.

Comment: After you issue a ModifyVolumeWhile the volume is in the optimizing state,the volume enters first the Modifying state, then the Optimizing state, and finally the Complete state. Volume performance is in between the source and target configuration specifications. More details here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/monitoring-volume-modifications.html

Comment: Ah, a state rather than an operation. Gotcha thanks.